# Is this home page well organized and what can I do to improve performance here?

Tags: html

My page has been loading a bit slower than I want it to.

The website is [www.digitechlab.com](http://www.digitechlab.com/)

I segregated so many files because they were pretty big and I wanted to be able to work on just one section of that page at a time without running the risk of breaking the entire page. This way I could work on, say, the header on its own.

Here is what I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <title>DigiTech Dental Lab - Dental Lab Services- Digital Dental Restorations</title>
  <meta name="keywords" content="dental lab, dentist laboratory, dental restorations, digital dental, dental implants, dental bridges, implant system, implant abutments, Bruxzir, IPS.emax, Prismatik, cad/cam technology" />
  <meta name="description" content="DigiTech dental lab offers CAD/CAM technology and digital dentistry to provide quality dental restorations, crowns and bridges at a competitive price." />
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="" /> <!-- not shown -->
  <meta name="y_key" content="" /> <!-- not shown -->
  <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="" /> <!-- not shown -->
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/head-styles-scripts.html" -->    
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/header.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-museo500.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body class="bgWht container-bg">
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/header.html" -->

  <div id="homePageHeader">
    <div id="headerTagline">
      <h1>CAD/CAM Digital Dental Restorations</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="responsiveHeaderContainer blkBorder">

    <div id="headerLogo">
      <img src="/img/home/bruxzir-bridge.png" />
    </div>

    <div id="headerModelImageContainer"><div id="headerModelImage"></div></div>

    <div id="headerCopy">
      <p>At DigiTech Dental Restorations, we take great pride in offering you quality products at a competitive price. Our dedicated team uses state-of-the-art CAD/CAM processes and equipment to fabricate each restoration, ensuring each crown or bridge is created with an unsurpassed degree of precision. The DigiTech staff is specially trained in monolithic BruxZir material, and our experience is evident in every BruxZir case you prescribe. From crowns &amp; bridges to Inclusive<sup>&reg;</sup> Implant Abutments, DigiTech is committed to both dentist and patient satisfaction.</p>      
    </div>

    <div id="headerCTA">
      <div>
        <a href="tel:888-336-1301">
          <div>
            Schedule a pickup<br>
            888-336-1301
          </div>  
        </a>
      </div>
    </div> 

  </div> <!-- end of responsiveContainer -->
</div> <!-- end of homePageHeader -->

<!--#include file="/_includes/template/home-page/home-page-nav.html" -->
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/home-page/home-page-videos.html" -->

<!--#include file="/_includes/template/footer.html" -->
<!--#include file="/_includes/template/scripts.html" -->
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me from a code review perspective, the font choice is not so good. It looks ugly on my machine.

Comment: @tomdemuyt , I am guessing Google Chrome on PC, and you are referring to the page titles? I only added the ttf of Myriad, as that is all the designers gave me. or are you referring to the font that is sitewide? I used 'sintony' from Google fonts, are you not a fan of it? Thanks for pointing that out, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Yeah, Sintony is bad.

Comment: When you change `bgWht` to be a different colour than white, the class becomes misleading. Never put colour names into CSS classes: describe the content instead. The point of CSS is to provide the ability to change how the page looks without changing the page content. If you have to change the HTML and the CSS to change how it looks, fundamentally a mistake has been made. See also: http://www.csszengarden.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your structure looks good.

I am sure you have a reason for nesting so many `<div>`s

you know that you  can add classes to Tags as well, and you don't have to add them to only `<div>` tags you can add them to other tags.

it just looks like you are surrounding some tags with Div tags because you think you can only style them that way.

like this

```
<div id="headerTagline">
  <h1>CAD/CAM Digital Dental Restorations</h1>
</div>
```

you can change to this

```
<h1 id="headerTagline"> CAD/CAM Digital Dental Restorations </h1>
```

or

```
<h1 class="headerTagline">CAD/CAM Digital Dental Restorations</h1>
```